# How to deploy a web application in amazon server

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, amazon-web-services

I have created a web application using `jsp` and `mysql` database and I am running them on `Apache tomcat`. I have created the web application in `Netbeans` IDE now I need to host it on a server. how should I do that?. I saw `Amazon` provides 12 months of free cloud service if possible I want to host it in that. If I have to move my database then the root password would changed and if that happens then I would have to change the password in my `jsp scriplets`. How should I deal with the situations. My web application creates a excel sheet will it still work if it is hosted on the web server. I am sorry this not a programming question but I seriously need to do this and I am newbie this is my first web application which I would host it in the server. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

`amazon` provides free cloud service for 12 month, to host your project you have to do no change in your code, just have to host your project and mysql database there. and how to host it, [see video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNr7YqjjzOY) on `youTube`.

it will guide you.